# Error when trying to create a managed notebook in google cloud platfrom

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook

Hi I am trying to create a managed notebook in Google Cloud Platform, but when I click create I get the following error

```
Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Create Runtime API requests' and limit 'Create Runtime API requests per minute' of service 'notebooks.googleapis.com' for consumer
```

How do I go about this error? where should I go to Increase our quota?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I have got the same problem. For me the Quota of "Create Runtime API requests per minute" is set 0 and I cannot change that (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=notebooks.googleapis.com). 
Haven't figured a solution yet.

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're creating this Notebook in Vertex?

In the [before-you-begin](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/before-you-begin) docs they suggest checking your [quotas](https://console.cloud.google.com/quotas?_ga=2.155704632.267810827.1638383710-1138163559.1637749963) to see if GPU is listed, if it's not, you may have to [request an increase](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota).